# angular2 http post request can not receive parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-http

i wanna post a simple http request , but the backend can not receive the paramter

```
export class AppComponent {
  isMenuCollapsed$:Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private store:Store<reducers.State>,private http:Http) {

    this.isMenuCollapsed$ = this.store.select(reducers.getIsCollapsed);
    let body: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();

    body.set('username', 'admin');
    body.set('password', 'admin');
    let head = new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });
    http.post('api/user/auth',body).subscribe(v => console.log(v));
  }
}
```

this is my backend code:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class TestController {

    @GetMapping("/get")
    public String  test(){
        return "hello";
    }

    @PostMapping("/auth")
    public String  auth(HttpServletRequest request){
        return "username:" + request.getParameter("username") + 
                "|password:" + request.getParameter("password");
    }
}
```

when i use regular method it worked:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ez3pl.png)

but when i use angular http , return null
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ozu1r.png)

so  i hope someone can help me , thanks!!!

Comment: I don't think your code is right, because in POST methods you are supposed to be saving a response body that is wrapped in your data model for persistence. That also means that in your post you ought to be creating an object for persistence.

Comment: thanks very much , i just post an object and add @RequestBody annotation in the backend code . .  and  it working !   ^_^

Comment: can you pick my answer and have ourselves a nice day? :)

Answer (score 0):

I think instead og `getParameters` you should use something to get body of request. create simple object of username and password like

```
let body={username:"admin", password:"admin"}
```

Stringify body before passing to request.

```
this.http.post(...., Json.stringify(body))
```

Comment: thanks very much , i just post an object and add @RequestBody annotation in the backend code . .  and  it working !   ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the backend and front end post the object